# Determining If a Date is between Other Dates in excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, vlookup

I want to compare and identify if a date is between dates in a separate table.

```
Start          End  Project Employee
1-Jan-13    31-Dec-13   10      2
1-Jan-14    31-Dec-14   10      2
1-Jan-15    31-Dec-15   12      2
1-Jan-16    31-Dec-16   12      2
1-Jan-17    31-Dec-17   14      2
1-Jan-16    31-Dec-16   10      5
1-Jan-17    31-Dec-17   20      5
```

I am looking for the project id that employee was comparing the date with the date period available in the second table for the same employee.

```
Employee    Date     projectid
2         1-Jul-16      ?
2         1-Dec-16      ?
2         1-May-17      ?
5         1-Jul-16      ?
5         1-Dec-16      ?
```

Please help. I tried LOOKUP formula but couldnt control the cell range dynamically. `=LOOKUP(Date,start:end,project:project)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the projectid is numeric, you can use:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(I2=Employee)*(J2>=Start)*(J2<=End)*Project,1)
```

where

```
Employee    refers to:  =Sheet1!$D$2:$D$8
End         refers to:  =Sheet1!$B$2:$B$8
Project     refers to:  =Sheet1!$C$2:$C$8
Start       refers to:  =Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8
```

If the project was text, you would modify the formula to return the row number of the table, so as to look that up with the `INDEX` function.

eg: with your table column headers in row 1:

```
=INDEX(Project,AGGREGATE(14,6,(I2=Employee)*(J2>Start)*(J2<=End)*ROW(Project),1)-1)
```

If you have an older version of Excel, which does not have the `AGGREGATE` function, you can use:

```
=LOOKUP(1E+307,1/((I2=Employee)*(J2>=Start)*(J2<=End))*Project)
```

[image]

Oh, and if your table will be continually expanding, you could either set your various ranges to be larger than the largest expected range; or you could create a table and use Structured References.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, *a bit manual* but still works.

If you use **AND** function to compare your cell between two different cell, you will get either **TRUE** or **FALSE**.

Considering your Start and End columns are B and C columns and A column is your number column (Titles are on 1st row):

```
ID  Start   End Project Employee
1   1-Jan-13    31-Dec-13   10  2
2   1-Jan-14    31-Dec-14   10  2
3   1-Jan-15    31-Dec-15   12  2
4   1-Jan-16    31-Dec-16   12  2
5   1-Jan-17    31-Dec-17   14  2
6   1-Jan-16    31-Dec-16   10  5
7   1-Jan-17    31-Dec-17   20  5
```

And the other table is on B C and D columns (Titles are on 11th row.)

If you copy this formula to somewhere you will get the project ID number or 0 (which is anyone)

```
=IF(AND(C12>$B$2,C12<$C$2),1,IF(AND(C12>$B$3,C12<$C$3),2,IF(AND(C12>$B$4,C12<$C$4),3,IF(AND(C12>$B$5,C12<$C$5),4,IF(AND(C12>$B$6,C12<$C$6),5,IF(AND(C12>$B$7,C12<$C$7),6,IF(AND(C12>$B$8,C12<$C$8),7,0)))))))
```

And just simply fill the cells to the down and the other ones will automatically pop-up.